# How to send static object to Thymelaf view?

Tags: java, hibernate, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have been trying for a long time to send a static object to the view in the controller. But it's give me exception like
`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "cache.playerOfTheWeek.get(0).player.imgUrl"`

But sending the regular `model.addAttribute("players", playerRepository.findAll());` goes smoothly.

I searched in the net and realized that there were some problems with sending static objects to views.

But I need to send this particular pre-created and processed object.

```
    public String index(Model model) {
        //THATS GIVES EXCEPTION in view
        model.addAttribute("cache", PermanentObjects.cachedObject);

        // THIS WORKS PRETTY GOOD
        model.addAttribute("players", playerRepository.findAll());
        return "web/index";
    }
```

```
public class PermanentObjects{
    public static CachedObject cachedObject = new CachedObject();

    ......
}
```

```
    // THIS IS SOME METHOD IN SOME CLASS TO REFRESH PermanentObjects.cachedObject
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1800000)
    public void refreshCache(){
        try{
            // doing something with static object!
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "static object" in java. What you showed is a static reference to the object and it cannot cause an issue for you. Try to review your object structure and SpEL expression.

Comment: @SergiyDakhniy Yes man. You are right. I looked at my data again and it turns out there was an error. Thanks for the help))